# "Maximum call stack size exceeded" after upgrading to alpha version of antd

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, antd

Using **npm** I updated my `antd` dependency to `4.17.0-alpha.0`. When I tried to run my react app after I updated it, it throws an error.

The error:

```
./src/App.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-8-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-8-3!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-8-4!./src/App.less)

Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

The **App.less** (I believe there's nothing wrong with this):

```
@import "~antd/lib/style/themes/default.less";
@import "~antd/dist/antd.less";
@import "~antd/dist/antd.compact.less"; // Introduce the official compact less style entry file

.login-form-container {
  height: 80vh;
  .login-form {
    padding: 30px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    .button {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
}

.footer {
  background-color: @primary-color;
  .text {
    color: #fff;
  }
}

.title {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#notif {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header-icon {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: @black;
}

.page-header {
  margin: 5px;
}

.content-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  min-height: 70vh;
  margin: 10px 25px;
}
```

**(P.S.)** The reason why I want to update to the alpha version because of the Drawer component. The Drawer component has an `extra` prop which is available only in the latest alpha version. Here's the [Drawer Documentation](https://ant.design/components/drawer/#API). Maybe I missed something.

I am new to Ant Design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install new alpha release to fix it.

```
npm install --save antd@4.17.0-alpha.2
```